# Android - Migrating from Google API v1 to v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on an old android application upgrading it from the Google API v1 to v2. I have a class that extends OverlayItem and was wondering what this has changed to in version 2 of the Google API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it has changed to something since the whole concept of displaying items has changed. You don't need to have separate `Overlay` to display items on a map. Instead, you add items directly to the map object. But if you insist, I would say it has changed to [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).